# Could not load type '<type name>' - Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an WebApp that i'm developing I've finished it and it works locally however when I upload it I get

Could not load type 'MyApp.GenerateData'

my asp page contains this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GenerateData.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyApp.GenerateData" %>
```

My GenerateData.aspx.cs code :

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class GenerateData : PageEstateAdministrator
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             // DO WORK
        }
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like your server don't have the dll wich is MyApp.GenerateData. Did you deploy the DLL or just the ASPX file?

Comment: I published it with Visual studio's tool

Comment: Check if your IIS is configured to use .NET FrameWork. Check if it is on the same version as your WebApp.

Comment: for the dll it generated a "MyApp.dll" but It doesn't have a "MyApp.GenerateData.dll"

Comment: IIS is already hosting an ASP website so I guess that it's configured to use .Net FrameWork abd It's configured for the same version

Comment: "MyApp.dll" is suficient, your class may be there. And "PageEstateAdministrator" ? How it is referenced? What is the namespace?

Comment: I haven't declared a namespace in PageEstateAdministrator

Comment: I just added MyApp as namespace on all my classes but I get the same error

Comment: Did you recompile it, and tried to deploy again?

Comment: Alsoe verify in your webserver if the dlls exist.

Comment: yeah I've recompiled it several times and get the same result
the dlls are all there if MyApp.dll is sufficiant

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't be sufficiant, the site works fine locally